# I gana make a music player, which pause playing when call answering and restart it when the answering is finished

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, media-player, phone-call

I need to make a music player which pause playing when call answering and restart the music playing when the answering is finished by broadcast receiver.
who can help me by a simple example please?
It is a really emergentlly need. so help me If you can.

thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

This works for me but it is not a good answer because of some conflicts:
Write it on your activity:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    // Start music when call answering is finished
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    // Stop music when call answering
    super.onStop();

    myMediaPlayer.pause();
}
```